# Adding an attributes column to WooCommerce admin products list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product

I was given code from someone on the Wordpress forum, but it isn't quite right.

It has created a column in my Product Admin called Attributes, and it is bringing in the name of the attributes, but not options. i.e. it looks like

- "coloursizeyearcountry"

And I would like

- "Colour = Red, Size = large, Year = 2020, Country = UK"

or something like it.

The code I have so far is:

```php
function add_product_column( $columns ) {
    //add column
    $columns['new_column'] = __( 'New column', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'add_product_column', 10, 1 );

function add_product_column_content( $column, $postid ) {
    if ( $column == 'new_column' ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = wc_get_product( $postid );
        
        // Get Product Variations
        $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        
        foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute ) {
            $attribute_name = $product_attribute->get_name();
            
            echo str_replace( 'pa_', '', $attribute_name );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'add_product_column_content', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will help you get what you want. Explanation via the comment tags added in the code

```php
function add_product_column( $columns ) {
    //add column
    $columns['new_column'] = __( 'New column', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'add_product_column', 10, 1 );

function add_product_column_content( $column, $postid ) {
    if ( $column == 'new_column' ) {

        // output variable
        $output = '';

        // Get product object
        $product = wc_get_product( $postid );

        // Get Product Variations - WC_Product_Attribute Object
        $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

        // Not empty, contains values
        if ( !empty( $product_attributes ) ) {

            foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute ) {
                // Get name
                $attribute_name = str_replace( 'pa_', '', $product_attribute->get_name() );

                // Concatenate
                $output = $attribute_name . ' = ';

                // Get options
                $attribute_options = $product_attribute->get_options();

                // Not empty, contains values
                if ( !empty( $attribute_options ) ) {

                    foreach ($attribute_options as $key => $attribute_option ) {
                        // WP_Term Object
                        $term = get_term($attribute_option); // <-- your term ID

                        // Not empty, contains values
                        if ( !empty( $term ) ) {
                            $term_name = $term->name;

                            // Not empty
                            if ( $term_name != '' ) {

                                // Last loop
                                end($attribute_options);
                                if ( $key === key($attribute_options) ) {
                                    // Concatenate
                                    $output .= $term_name;                                  
                                } else {
                                    // Concatenate
                                    $output .= $term_name . ', ';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                echo $output . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'add_product_column_content', 10, 2 );
```

[image: Result]