# WooCommerce unit (from attribute value) after price in the cart example: $9.99/kg

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, price, suffix

I have managed the following code to put specific attributes of weight or piece behind the price with the following code:

```php
function pakiranje() {
    global $product;
    $attribute  = 'pakiranje';
    $abv        = $product->get_attribute($attribute);
    if(!empty($abv))
    {
       return '/' . $abv;
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'pakiranje',15);
```

screenshot looks like this:

[image]

HOWEVER, i need to also apply this to the cart checkout as it is not visible there.

Comment: The 2nd parameter you can access is actually `$product` (where you use `$instance`). 
Through `$product` you have access to all properties of the product, including attributes. You can get them using `$product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60551992/11987538 (line: 19)
and use the necessary information from there

Comment: @7uc1f3r Thanks again for the input, i've finally figured it out as you can see in the updated post....now im only trying to apply the unit after the price in the cart. Thanks again!